# Build / create .wsp using MSBuild

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, msbuild

I have the below machine
OS: Windows server 2016
SharePoint: 2016
Visual Studio: 2015 Professional

When we publish any sharepoint project using Visual studio, it produces .wsp file but when we try to build the same using msbuild only .dll is generated but not .wsp file

tried to refer msbuild.exe from framework (msbuild_1 in below code) and programfiles (msbuild_2 in below code)

```
set msbuild_1 ="C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe"
set msbuild_2 ="C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\MSBuild.exe"

set config=Release
set outdir2=C:\out\
rd /S /Q "%outdir2%"
%msbuild_1% /p:Configuration=%config% /m "C:\Test\test.csproj" /t:Package /p:BasePackagePath=%outdir2%

%msbuild_2% /p:Configuration=%config% /m "C:\Test\test.csproj" /t:Package /p:BasePackagePath=%outdir2%
```

both version of msbuild.exe generates only .dll but not .wsp

Is there anyway we can generate .wsp file from msbuild.exe or powershell?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a SharePoint package with Msbuild you can refer to the following steps:

1. Run Command Prompt in the Windows Start menu.
2. Change to the SharePoint project folder.
3. Run this command: `msbuild /t:Package ProjectFileName` change the ProjectFileName to your project name.

You can also refer to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/sharepoint/how-to-create-a-sharepoint-solution-package-by-using-msbuild-tasks?view=vs-2022#build-a-sharepoint-package) about how to build, clean, and validate a sharepoint package using command-line MSBuild tasks.

Comment: this builds and generates only .dll file, do not package as .wsp file.

Comment: From this page (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/stand-alone-msbuild-does-not-create-wsp/161812 ) we can see that use the standalone MSBuild tool for building and package the SharePoint solution, a WSP is not created, however when use the one bundled with Visual Studio, the WSP is created. Maybe you can update your visual studio and Msbuild and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command in PowerShell after changing the paths

```
$msbuildpath = ""
$csprojpath = ""
$OutputPath = ""
$vsversion = "14.0"
cd $msbuildpath 
.\msbuild.exe $csprojpath /p:IsPackaging=true  /p:OutputPath="$OutputPath" /p:Configuration=Release /p:VisualStudioVersion=$vsversion  /t:Package
```

the output will include the WSP files